# MSDOS - "The system could not find the file specified"

Tags: dos

I am trying to copy the contents of a log file to another log file using this command:

```
type \\server\f$\Test path\Test.log >> \\server2\f$\Logs\Testpath\Test.log
```

This has always worked in the path, but recently I have changed the location (path) to Test.log.  The path is slightly longer.  I now get an error:

> The system could not find the file specified

I have googled this statement and the common responses are: 1) check the filename exists, 2) check the filename is not corrupt 3) Check the server is online.

I have done all of this.  Is there a restriction on the number of characters a path can have? If there is then is there a workaround?

**UPDATE 12/07/2012 09:49 GMT**
Adding quotes around the path seems to resolve the problem.  Why does adding quotes resolve the problem?

Comment: Did you check the destination path? Is destination path correct

Comment: @Esen, as stated in the original question, I did check the destination path.

Comment: @w0051977 old post but no one has answered your question.  MSDOS see a space as the end of string, not to mention the problem it has with long file names.  `C:\Program Files\ ` will be seen as `C:\Program` without the quotes.  Another way to solve it is to use short file names `C:\Progra~1\ ` but this can become complicated if more than one file/folder at the same level have the same start to the name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that the source path had a space in it.  Adding quotes around the path resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Type is to examine a file, not to copy.

Also, if server is an actual server and not a folder, then you should be using two slashes (\server\share)

Example:

```
 copy \\server\f$\Sourcepath\Test.log  \\server2\f$\Logs\Destpath\Test.log /y
```

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: I am using two slashes? I want to copy the contents of one file into the contents of another.

Comment: Yes, the code that was initially posted showed only 1 slash, I see it has been corrected.  Still if you want to copy, use the copy command and not the type command.

Comment: I have always used the type command.  Is there a restriction on the number of characters?

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is not how type is used.  From MSDN: Type Displays the contents of a text file. Use the type command to view a text file without modifying it.  Syntax type [Drive:][Path] FileName.  why not just TRY it my way and see if it works.  Even your type syntax is wrong, with 1 file then >> then a second file.

Comment: The problem with 'copy' is that Test.log on server 2 would be overwritten.  I want to copy the contents (lines) in Test.log on server 1 and paste them into Test2.log on server 2.

Comment: So you want to append them?  Is that was you are saying?  Because you didn't say that originally.  To append files, specify a single file for destination, but multiple files for source (using wildcards or file1+file2+file3 format).  That is from http://www.computerhope.com/copyhlp.htm

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13753/discussion-between-grayfox374-and-w0051977)